# Get request keeps getting cancelled when an URL is called from Salesforce communities site

Tags: salesforce, google-chrome-devtools, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am trying to launch an URL from one of the pages in our community site. The URL leads to an third party vendor. The URL is launched via a button which launches an Aura component to handle the redirect.

Whenever the URL is launched it is creating a spam on vendor server because the initial request keeps getting cancelled and resubmitted. This is evident in the network log.

All the red lines in the log screenshot are the external URL that we are calling. The interesting thing is after many attempts (~100 + requests) it finally gives in and URL is accessed.

Can someone please help me in identifying what could be going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was an infinite loop happening within the flow that was launching the Aura container causing the request to be cancelled.